# analytic solution to a seemingly easy linear system of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]
How to solve this PDE, as in this screenshot and the equations?

$x_X(X,Y)=1+x(X,Y)+y(X,Y)$
$y_Y(X,Y)=1+x(X,Y)+y(X,Y)$

where subscripts are partial derivatives.

Comment: I suggest you type the equation using latex (pictures are not searchable). Also, what have you tried so far, what's your background?

Comment: Please express the equation without using Mathematica. If your question is Mathematica specific, there is a Stack Exchange for that.

Comment: not mathematica specific

Comment: @SeverinSchraven no clue of analytic solution and I'm of math background

Comment: I was responding to a comment that has since been deleted.

Comment: I'd start with finding some constant solution and then consider the homogeneous problem.